# VB Script FileSystemObject methods throwing 424 error

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have been searching the Internet for the past few hours trying to find a reason why this always throws a 424 Object required error in excel. Can someone explain why this is, and the best way to fix it?

```
Sub ImportXML()
'
' ImportXML Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k
'
Dim count As Integer
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubFolders FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyyyy\")
End Sub
```

Show Folders method

```
Sub ShowSubFolders(folder)
For Each Subfolder In folder.SubFolders
getFiles Subfolder
ShowSubFolders Subfolder
Next
End Sub
```

Get Files Method

```
Sub getFiles(folder)
For Each file In folder.Files
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = FSO.GetFileName(file) 'throws error here
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `GetFileName` expects a string filepath+name, not a `File` object: it's basically a utliity function for parsing out the "name" part of a file path.  If you already have a File object then `file.Name` is what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = FSO.GetFileName(file)
```

`object.GetFileName(pathspec)` but you are passing an object. So

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = FSO.GetFileName(file.name)
```

or more direct

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = dfile.name
```